# How to capture martian packets without letting the linux kernel to drop them and then catching them using raw sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, iptables

I'm trying to setup a network to simulate an Edge computing scenario with LTE. But the question here is more pertaining to IP tables and raw sockets on the server.
I have the following setup:
*PC-A is the Tower, PC-C is the LTE Core, PC-B is acting as intermediary and routing data using proxy ARPs*

- Cell phone wants to connect to a TCP server on PC-B(IP: 172.17.1.3)
- Cell phone(IP:192.172.0.2) sends packets to PC-A(IP: 172.17.1.1)
- The data from PC-A(172.17.1.1) generally has to reach LTE-EPC on 172.17.1.4 which is connected via PC-B(172.17.1.2 - 172.17.1.3 with proxy ARPs). And the data comes in the form of UDP packets to PC-B(IP: 172.17.1.2)
- I use NAT table and python script with raw sockets to send all of these UDP packets to a local port, do some filtering, decapsulate the GTP headers and send the TCP/IP packet to the TCP server on PC-B interface(172.17.1.3). I use the below iptables settings to do this

  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 172.17.1.4 --dport 2152  -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.1.2:7000

Until here everything works, the extracted TCP/IP packet also reaches the TCP server on 172.17.1.3. The server responds to these packets. For example, for the SYN packet from the cell phone, the server now sends out SYN, ACK. However, the server responds to the original source address 192.172.0.2.

**I want to catch these response TCP/IP packets from the TCP server 172.17.1.3 to 192.172.0.2 and do some GTP encapsulation before sending them back to PC-A.**

Can anyone tell me how I can use the iptables to tell the kernel to stop dropping these martian packets with destination address 192.172.0.2, but instead forward to a local ip and port, so I can read the same.

I can see the SYN, ACK responses from the server on wireshark. But I assume that these are dropped as I already tried to route it to local ip:port using a similar iptables rule from above.

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Does Linux not have GTP support built-in? It is weird that you are using a Python script to decapsulate GTP. If it doesn't have built-in GTP support, it definitely does have built-in tunnel support via tun/tap interfaces, and are you sure you shouldn't be using one of those?

Comment: with a tun/tap interface, instead of trying to catch this weird packet and do special processing, *Linux would send it directly to your program* because the routing table would say that the 192.168 subnet was on the other side of your program's tunnel interface.

Comment: The think is i do not want all packets from the cell phone to be handled this way. So, i use python to filter packets based on the final destination address and port.

Comment: You might still find it convenient to use a tun/tap interface for the packets to find their way back from B - you could tell B that the 192.172 subnet is through the tunnel. I don't really understand what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to build a edge server. The python script filters based on IP whether the data is for local processing or actual internet. So it respectively redirects the traffic to the local server or the cloud. However, the local server replies to the packets with the initial source address of the cell phones. I need to somehow catch these and send them back on the udp channel to the tower. Also, before I send it back on this channel, I need to add GTP headers, so the tower understands to which cell phone this data is for.

Comment: @user253751, would a tunnel/tap interface allow me to modify the data packets before I receive and send them? could you link me to some useful material if this is possible. Thank you!

Comment: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a tun/tap interface could be useful here. [Here's the official Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt).

Both these interface types allow a program to create a virtual network interface. This is designed for tunnels and VPNs and it seems like that is exactly what you are creating.

According to the linked documentation, you may create an interface by opening `/dev/net/tun` (`O_RDWR`) and issuing this ioctl to initialize it:

```
struct ifreq req;
memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
req.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN; // or IFF_TAP
strncpy(req.ifr_name, "tunnel%d", IFNAMSIZ); // optional; leave it blank to get a default name; you don't have to have a %d
ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, &req); // error check omitted for demonstration
// req.ifr_name now contains the name that was actually selected
```

After the ioctl you have a virtual network interface in your system. You can configure IP addresses, routes, whatever.

Any time the kernel sends a packet out through your interface it will go into a queue and you'll be able to `read` it. Any time you `write` to the interface the kernel will process it as if it's a real packet that just arrived.

You will need to configure networking like it's a real interface. Set up a static route so that 192.172.0.0/16 (or whatever your subnet is) is reached through the tunnel interface. I'm not sure if Linux will let you do this without giving it an address; you might have to give it a dummy address like 192.172.255.254. Or a completely unrelated address like 1.2.3.4 and then let Linux think there's another router in front of your cellphone subnet. Or maybe it will just work without an address - not sure.

The difference between "tun" and "tap" is whether Ethernet processing happens or not (IP tunnel vs Ethernet tap). I expect *tun* is right for your application. If you choose *tap* then Linux will also use ARP and so on, and the interface will certainly need an address.

You might find it convenient to use the tunnel interface in both directions, or just one. IP packets aren't required to take the same route in both directions. This is the "correct" way to implement a tunnel, so you might find that a lot of mysterious bugs go away by using it.

Comment: thank you, i will read up on this and see if it works.